# Shell append redirection replaces existing text?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, unix

For our school assignment, we have to implement input/output redirection. I managed to get the input and output redirection work, but I am facing an issue with append redirection.

I am using testfile.txt:

```
test line 1
test line 2
```

When the user types ls >> testfile.txt, I expect the output from ls to be added to the testfile. At this moment, the test lines get replaced by the output of the ls program.

The rights that I am using to open the files are the following:

```
    file = open(redirect.getNewFile().c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
```

Does anyone have an idea where it goes wrong?

Thanks in forward.

Comment: You open with `O_TRUNC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced O_TRUNC with O_APPEND.

Comment: You can accept this answer, so your question will show as solved.